# quicker way to open an ubuntu terminal in a particular directory

Tags: ubuntu

How can I set up some quick access ubuntu terminals to directories other than the user's home?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general Úbuntu functionality. You may be able to get help on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal`
`killall nautilus && nautilus`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Apparix](http://www.micans.org/apparix/). To install it run `sudo apt-get install apparix` then `apparix --shell-examples`.

Once you install this, it basically is a bookmark manager for your terminal. Run `bm <name>` to bookmark your current path as a custom name, then use `to <name>` to go to that location later.

Comment: What can I do if after running `sudo apt-get install apparix` and `apparix --shell-examples`, I get `bm: command not found` when I try to create a bookmark? `apparix` works, but its shortcuts don't. (I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.)

Comment: Answering my question above. It was needed to add aliases `go` and `to` manually. (1) Run `apparix --shell-examples` and copy the BASH code between `BASH-style functions\n---` and `---\nCSH-style aliases` (2) `$ gedit ~/.bashrc` and paste the copied text in the end of the file. Save. (3) Relaunch the terminal.

Answer (score 11):

**Create custom keyboard shortcuts.** E.g. pressing `Ctrl + Alt + J` to open Terminal in a specific directory is blazingly fast.

In Ubuntu 11.10 you can do this by going to `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts (tab)`.

In the command field of a new custom keyboard shortcut window, type `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/dir`.

To change the keyboard shortcut to open Terminal in the default directory (default is `Ctrl + Alt + T`), look for the launcher shortcuts ("Launchers").

Comment: It should be stressed that this only makes a terminal point to *one* directory, not the one you're browsing in, so it's really not as useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can edit `~/.bashrc` and add the line `CD /path/to/desired/directory`. Everytime you open a new shell, it'll default to that directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can give gnome-terminal a working directory.  If you add a terminal applet to a panel, you can then get its properties and put the options to do this in the `command` field. Like this for the `Desktop` directory:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory Desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

Install Nautilus Actions Configuration from Software Center. Then go to Systems->Preferences->Nautilus Actions Configurations and then create an action named "Open Terminal here" for folders with the command

```
gnome-terminal
```

and parameter as

```
--working-directory=%d
```

After that, you can right-click on any folder and get a terminal window right away.

Comment: I think this is a successful answer. But this didn't work for me.. pls help.

Comment: --working-directory is broken in Ubuntu 16.04 due to this gnome-terminal bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1587154 If you'd like this fixed, go there, login and click the 'affects me too' button.